# Using Hot Keys with Monaco Editor?

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I'm trying to use hot keys in a monaco editor to run a function when **cmd + enter** is pressed using the 'react-hotkeys-hook' npm package.

I have it working when I click off from the monaco editor. It seems when the cursor is focused in the editor, the hot keys don't work.

Is there a way to make the hot keys work while also typing in the monaco editor instead of manually clicking off to anther div?

Here is some of the code I'm working on:

```
import React from "react";
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { useHotkeys } from "react-hotkeys-hook";

export default function codeEditor(props) {
useHotkeys("cmd+enter", () => runCode());

function runCode() {
  alert('Running code...')
}

return (
    <div className="editor-container">
      <Editor
        defaultValue={`Hello World`}
        onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
        width="100%"
        height="80vh"
        theme="vs-dark"
        fontSize='20px'
        defaultLanguage="javascript"
        options={{
          fontSize: '18px'
        }}  
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used react-hotkeys-hook, but I registered multiple shortcuts in the editor, including <kbd>cmd</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
            editor.addAction({
                id: "executeCurrentAndAdvance",
                label: "Execute Block and Advance",
                keybindings: [KeyMod.CtrlCmd | KeyCode.Enter],
                contextMenuGroupId: "2_execution",
                precondition: blockContext,
                run: () => {
                    this.executeCurrentContext(false, true);
                },
            });
```

with the precondition:

```
        const blockContext = "editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible && !renameInputVisible && !inSnippetMode " +
            "&& !quickFixWidgetVisible";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following call form:

```
useHotkeys("cmd+enter", () => runCode(), {enableOnTags: ['INPUT','TEXTAREA','SELECT']});
```

"enableOnTags: string[] is used to enable listening to hotkeys in form fields".

Answer (score -1):

In version `4.3.8` of react-hotkeys-hook, this can be achieved using

```js
  useHotkeys("ctrl+b", () => console.log("hello"), {
    preventDefault: true,
    enableOnFormTags: true,
  });
```